# Minecraft Crafting Recipe 1.6.4 Is not working

Tags: java, minecraft

Hey sorry I'm going to CoderDojo and we're modding Minecraft together and for Christmas they have given me homework. Anyway, I'm wondering why my code isn't working? Mind having a look?

```
package tutorial.generic;

import tutorial.generic.Generic;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.src.BaseMod;
import net.minecraft.src.ModLoader;

public class GenericCrafting extends BaseMod{
public void addRecipes()
 {
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Generic.genericPick, 1), new Object[]{"GGG"," s ", " s ", 'G', Generic.genericIngot, 's', Item.stick});
}

public void load()
{
        this.addRecipes();
}

public String getVersion()
{
        return "Version 1.0";
}}
```

Basically it will not show up in minecraft when I craft it.

Comment: What APIs are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the name of the base mod class for a ModLoader mod needs to be prefixed with "mod_".

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it!